# Microsoft Cognitive Service Internal Server Error for /vision/v1.0/analyze

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I made a small program to test Microsoft Cognitive Service, but it always return

```
{
 "code":"InternalServerError",
 "requestId":"6d6dd4ec-9840-4db3-9849-a6497094fa4c",
 "message":"Internal server error."
}
```

The code I'm using is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import httplib, urllib, base64

headers = {
    # Request headers
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '53403359628e420ab85a516a79ba1bd0',
}

params = urllib.urlencode({
    # Request parameters
    'visualFeatures': 'Categories,Tags,Adult,Description,Faces',
    'details': '{string}',
})

try:
    conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.projectoxford.ai')

    conn.request("POST", "/vision/v1.0/analyze?%s" % params, 
       '{"url":"http://static5.netshoes.net/Produtos/bola-umbro-neo-liga-futsal/28/D21-0232-028/D21-0232-028_zoom1.jpg?resize=54g:*"}', headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    data = response.read()
    print(data)
    conn.close()
except Exception as e:
    print("[Errno {0}] {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))
```

Am I doing something wrong or it's a generalized server problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the **params** variable. When defining which visual features you would like to extract you can specify specific details from the image, as described in the [documentation](https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/56f91f2d778daf23d8ec6739/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499e1fa). The **details** field, if used, must be initialized with one of the valid *string* options available (currently, only supporting the "Celebrities" option, that would identify which celebrity is in the image). In this case, you initialized the **details** field with *literally* the placeholder noted in the documentation ('{string'}). That caused the system to give an internal error.

To correct that, you should try:

```
params = urllib.urlencode({
    # Request parameters
   'visualFeatures': 'Categories,Tags,Adult,Description,Faces',
   'details': 'Celebrities',
})
```

(PS: Have already reported this behavior to Microsoft Cognitive Services.)

Comment: Alternatively, omit the `details` field entirely.